# two column layout , one column vertical middle

Tags: css, layout, vertical-alignment

see 
   [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LQEM7/)

need work at ie6+

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">
        right content fixed width
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        left content flexible widthffffffffffff<br/>
        left content flexible widthffffffffffff<br/>
        left content flexible widthffffffffffff<br/>
        left content flexible widthffffffffffff<br/>
        left content flexible widthffffffffffff<br/>
        left content flexible widthffffffffffff<br/>
        left content flexible widthffffffffffff<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

how to let right div have the same height as left, and the content be vertical middle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supporting IE6, huh? Well, here's a really non-ideal solution in the spirit of IE6. :|

---

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        left content flexible widthffffffffffff<br/>
        left content flexible widthffffffffffff<br/>
        left content flexible widthffffffffffff<br/>left content flexible widthffffffffffff<br/>left content flexible widthffffffffffff<br/>left content flexible widthffffffffffff<br/>left content flexible widthffffffffffff<br/>
        <div class="right-column"></div>
        <div class="right-content">right content fixed width</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.right-column {
    width: 180px;
    height: 10000px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fc0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.right-content {
    height: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.left {
    background: #e8f6fe;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 180px;
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1; /* hasLayout */
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

## **[(IE6-viewable JSFiddle results here)](http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/WbaKd/embedded/result/)**

---

It works in these parts:

- Apply `zoom: 1;` property to get `overflow: hidden;` property working via `hasLayout`
- Move the right column into the left column's tag
- Have two separate parts to the right column

  - A really tall empty `div` for the column background (gives illusion of equal column heights)
  - The content `div` with a specified `height` for vertical positioning
- Position the right column elements absolutely in the top-right of the relatively-positioned left column
- Add right padding to the left column equal to the right column's width (to avoid the right column covering the left column)
- Vertical align the right content based off its specified `height`
- Add `min-width: 100px;` to the left column so modern browsers don't cut off the content when the window is too small

---

*Cautionary Notes:*

- You will need to adjust the `height` and `margin-top` of `.right-content` to fit the content
- The right column's content will get cut off if it has a larger height than the left column

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I added `position;absolute` to the right div, removed `float:right` and added `right:0px`

http://jsfiddle.net/LQEM7/2/

Comment: The problem with your solution is that, when you resize the screen (smaller), the left div goes behind the right div. So its not a good solution for @looping